# system.timers.timer doesn't fire the elapsed event on the server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-services, timer

I have a Web Service and i used timers inside it. when i run the service application inside my vs2010 it work's like a charm. but when i deploy it to the remote server it doesn't fire the ElapsedEventHandler. I used a Logger to log the events and i set the permissions for write into the log file.
Let me explain more. I'm trying to write a service which waits for a job, and the job is sending email to a big list. and emails should be send by 20 secs interval.
here is some part of my code:

```
 public class EmailSender : IEmailSender
{

    Queue<AdvEmail> ListOfEmails = new Queue<AdvEmail>();
    List<EmailJob> EmailJobs = new List<EmailJob>();

    Timer timerFetchJobs = null;
    Timer timerSendEmails = null;

    public EmailSender()
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Log("init service");
            timerFetchJobs = new Timer();
            timerFetchJobs.Interval = 5 * 1000;
            timerFetchJobs.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerFetchJobs_Elapsed);
            timerFetchJobs.Enabled = true;
            timerSendEmails = new Timer();
            timerSendEmails.Interval = 20 * 1000;
            timerSendEmails.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timerSendEmails_Elapsed);
            timerSendEmails.Enabled = true;
            timerFetchJobs.Start();
            timerSendEmails.Start();
            Logger.Log("init service Ended Succefully");
            Logger.Log("timerFetchJobs.Enabled=" + timerFetchJobs.Enabled.ToString());
            Logger.Log("timerSendEmails.Enabled=" + timerSendEmails.Enabled.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error in InitService. Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void timerSendEmails_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timerSendEmails.Stop();
        Logger.Log("Checking for Emails in the Queue");
        // some statments here

        timerSendEmails.Start();
    }

    void timerFetchJobs_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timerFetchJobs.Stop();
        try
        {
            FetchJobsFromDB();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("Error in timerFetchJobs. Message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        timerFetchJobs.Start();
    }
```

when i go to the service addreess from browser, it initializes and logs the init level correctly, but no clue  of firing timers!! which i dont know why??
what I'm doing wrong?
thanks

Edit:
**here is the log file when i run it locally:**

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :init service-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :init service Ended Succefully-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :timerFetchJobs.Enabled=True-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :timerSendEmails.Enabled=True-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:14  :  :Checking for Jobs in the Database-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:16  :  :There is a new job. job name is Pad 71-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:19  :  :Adding Emails for th job Pad 71-------------------------------

**And here is the log file when i deploy it to remote server**

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :init service-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :init service Ended Succefully-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :timerFetchJobs.Enabled=True-------------------------------

Log Entry : 1392/01/30 08:47:09  :  :timerSendEmails.Enabled=True-------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed th Logger class and problem solved. i don't know why it didn't work on server.